# AppGyver does not run config.xml?

Tags: xml, cordova, phonegap-plugins, appgyver

The problem I am encountering is that when I use `steroids connect`, it runs without the config.xml, and in this file I have many things such as fullscreen mode etc.

How can I make steroids appgyver run the config.xml file?

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<widget id="com.example.hello" version="0.0.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
    <name>HelloWorld</name>
    <description>
        A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready event.
    </description>
    <author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
        Apache Cordova Team
    </author>
    <content src="index.html" />
    <access origin="*" />
    <preference name="phonegap-version" value="3.7.0" />
    <preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="19" />
    <preference name="orientation" value="landscape" /><!--No rotation-->
    <preference name="fullscreen" value="true" /><!--Hides the menu on top-->
    <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
    <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="10000" />
</widget>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is some [documentation](http://docs.appgyver.com/supersonic/guides/architecture/app-config-files/) on the new config files in Appgyver.

You can build a version of your application and adjust the orientation mode in the [Build Settings](http://docs.appgyver.com/tooling/build-service/build-settings/build-settings-for-android/) [image: Android Build Settings Orientation Options]

Here is a short [discussion](https://muut.com/appgyver#!/steroids:phonegap-configxml) where one of the Appgyver team members answers a question about `config.xml`.